# Billboard to scene camera?

Tags: camera, constraints, geometry-nodes

Most of the various tips I've seen on constructing billboards (at least, without the use of the old legacy particle system) involves constraining them to the camera. This works fine for a scene with a single camera, but oftentimes, particularly in animations, you'll want multiple, and they can be easily switched using markers.
However, to the best of my understanding, this sort of breaks the "constrain to object" method of creating billboards.

Ideally, somehow tracking the object to whatever the active scene camera is would solve this problem. How could this be done? Geometry nodes? Some sort of driver-and-constraint wizardry?

EDIT: Here's a very basic example .blend file.
[image]

Comment: So it doesn't work if you add a child of constraint, or even parenting? I'm not sure, but maybe it's possible to animate parents? Or what you could do is animate the influence of each child of modifier? For example, the influence is 1 on the child of constraint on a camera. Then animate the value to be 0 when the second child of comes, then add another child of and animate the values, and on and on and on.

Comment: I'm not currently posting an answer since I may turn out to be wrong, and you would have probably tried this. Have you?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible (at least partially) with Geometry Nodes (in combination with drivers). Do you have a blend file for us to try this on your concrete example?

Comment: @quellenform added a .blend file.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry that technically would achieve the same result, but it's an enormous amount of tedium and incredibly impractical, especially if you have a lot of billboards, a lot of cameras, and want to have the freedom to change the timing later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Geometry Nodes* could be helpful here.

[image]

If you put a driver into a *Group Input*, and enter the euler rotation of the active camera there, you can transfer this rotation directly to your object.

[image]

1. Create a *Group Input* of type *Vector*.
2. Choose *Single Value* for the driver, select the current scene, and enter *camera.rotation_euler.x* as path. Repeat this for the other axes.
3. In the *Geometry Nodes* you can then transfer this rotation directly to your instance by first converting the object with the node `Geometry to Instance`, and then using the node `Rotate Instances`.

[image]

**PS, just to be clear:** *Geometry Nodes* are NOT necessary here, because you can also control the rotation of an object directly with the driver or constraints. It was just fun to answer the question with *Geometry Nodes* as well. But who knows what else you could do here ...?

Comment: What? Why don't you just drive rotation values instead of using geonodes without reason?

Comment: @Crantisz Simply because here was (also) asked for *Geometry Nodes*, and that would be the solution with *Geometry Nodes* ...besides I like *Geometry Nodes* :D

Comment: Also avoid using scripted expressions in drivers. They used python to operate, which should be slower. I know you can't even notice the difference in this case, but then you  start using plenty of drivers it does make sense.

Comment: @Crantisz Good point! As always, a very useful hint!

Comment: Works perfectly in the scene the driver was created in--can't figure out how to append, link, or otherwise transfer it into any other scene, though, which really limits its utility...any advice?

Comment: @Legoman You could just select a different scene in the Driver Properties.

Comment: you can use the object info node instead of drivers.

Comment: @shmuel No, unfortunately not in this case, because these are switchable cameras, and with `Object Info` alone it is not possible to determine which camera is currently active.