# Parent object to active camera? [Solved]

Tags: camera, geometry-nodes, parent

I've tried several ways to change the density of grass according to the **active** camera distance without success.

Is there any way to parent an object to the active camera? Or to get the active camera location in geometry nodes?
For a single camera it's easy, but to have it automatically adjusted when switching cameras seems impossible.

Am I missing something?

Edit ANSWER : this can be done through drivers as inputs of the geometry node group.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Billboard to scene camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267801/billboard-to-scene-camera) ...With this solution you would at least be able to determine the position of the active camera.

Comment: Indeed! I added 6 drivers (for location and rotation of the active camera) as inputs and was able to achieve the expected result! Thank you!

Still it would be nice to have a 'local camera' geometry node to spare the hassle ;)